# How to make iso from install Ubuntu.18.04 from VmWare Workstation?

Tags: iso, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware workstation pro and manage to install ubuntu 18.04 and configure it. I also install my work software. Now I want to use this Ubuntu 18.04 and make iso so I can install another 10 workstation.

How to make iso from install Ubuntu.18.04 from VmWare Workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply create an OVF file from your VM (File -> Export to OVF) or create a template and deploy said template : https://www.dtonias.com/create-vm-template-vmware-workstation/

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had a bit strugle but feeling happy.